# Unable to target .NET 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, multi-targeting

What steps are needed to target previous versions of the .NET framework in Visual Studio 2010?

I installed Visual Studio and the .NET 2.0 SDK (from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en)), but only .NET 4.0 is in the list of available frameworks.

[image: Screenshot]

What am I missing?

Comment: How strange. I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: Can you change it in the project settings after creation?

Comment: what happens if you click "More frameworks" ?

Comment: Project settings are the same, and "more frameworks" links to the .NET framework download site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download and install [.NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en). .NET Framework 3.5 includes 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5, though it is not included with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I downloaded 3.5 SP1 instead of plain old 3.5.

Comment: That was the solution.  I would have never considered it (I already had it, but was having a heck of a time finding it).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The .NET 2.0 SDK doesn't actually include the .NET 2.0 framework. It is merely a collection of tools and header files; they are nowadays included with the [Windows SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK). You've already got that in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs` directory.

You'll need to download and install an earlier version of .NET. Using 3.5 SP1 is the best choice, and the download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&DisplayLang=en). Pick one that's appropriate for your language.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

I would suspect something like that would occur with an [Express edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express).

I use [Premium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_Premium) and 2.0 is definitely there.